# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-markers, angular6

I'm developing a web app with angular 6. I integrated google maps but marker click event is returning me an error.

Help me, thanks in advance.

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';

 @ViewChild('whereMap') gmapElement: any;
 map: google.maps.Map;
 marker: google.maps.Marker;

  initMapp() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    let location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
      center: location,
      zoom: 15,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: this.map,
      draggable: true,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      title: 'Got you!'
    });

  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', () => {
    console.log('marker clicked');
});

} else {
  alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
```

}

}

map initialized and marker is working fine, but im unable to fire click event.
i have called the initMapp() in ngOnInit().

Answer (score 0):

The `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, you are likely meeting a race condition. You should move `google.maps.event.addListener` inside geolocation callback, otherwise you can try to assign event listener before the marker element was created.

Google Maps JavaScript API error message `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '__e3_' of undefined` typically means that you try to assign event to non-existing DOM element.

Try the following

```
initMapp() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            let location = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

            this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, {
                center: location,
                zoom: 15,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            });

            this.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: this.map,
                draggable: true,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: 'Got you!'
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'click', () => {
                console.log('marker clicked');
            });
        });
    } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps!